# Set License in Azure Function

Tags: java, azure-functions

I have License file called Aspose.Total.Product.Family.lic for a third party API Aspose. I need to set the License by attaching this file along with Azure Function and Inside my function I should refer this file and set the License.

In a normal Java Application, I will do something like below.I will place the file in project and refer it as below

```
License license = new License();    
license.setLicense(App.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("Aspose.Total.Product.Family.lic"));
```

Can someone help me doing the same inside Azure Function ? Please let me know how to embed this file inside azure function and get reference to the same inside the azure function.

Comment: Hope this thread can provide you some references to solve your issue. https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/415

Answer (score 0):

Azure functions depend on a `function.json` file. What you could do is place your `license` file in the same directory and you can access it by

```
 var path = System.IO.Path.Combine(context.FunctionAppDirectory, "Aspose.Total.Product.Family.lic");
```

or the another way around is to upload the file in a blob storage and pull it whenever necessary. For more about blob storage refer [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-blob#input---example)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to load a file inside azure function either you can add in you project and mark as copy always,then using **Path.combine()** load the file and read,

**Dynamic**: If you want to read a file dynamical create blob storage and container read from blob.

More info abt blob [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-blob?tabs=in-process%2Cextensionv5%2Cextensionv3&pivots=programming-language-csharp)